# How to delete all the pods which are in Error/Init/CrashloopBckoff state at one shot

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubectl

I have tried below command. but this command gets all the pods which are not running for some reason any other way to do this

```
kubectl delete pods -A --field-selector=status.phase!=Running
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you are looking for, but uses awk and unix output piping.

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector 'status.phase=Failed' --all-namespaces | awk '{if ($4 != "Running") system ("kubectl -n " $1 " delete pods " $2 )}'
```

Comment: kubectl get pods --field-selector 'status.phase=Failed' --all-namespaces is not catching all the pods with STATUS != RUNNING .

Comment: @Gajukorse remove `--field-selector 'status.phase=Failed'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command for check the init pod with namespace like default-user and delete those pods.

`kubectl get pods -A | grep default-user | grep -i "init:" | awk '{if ($4 != "Running") system ("kubectl -n " $1 " delete pods " $2 )}'`

Answer (score 0):

To delete all running pods in the current namespace, use the below command

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector 'status.phase=Failed' | awk '{if ($3 != "Running") system ("kubectl delete pods " $1 )}'
```

Comment: The exact same answer has already been shared by Thomas above. Please do not make duplicate posts.

Comment: My reply is for the current namespace.